# Returning a viewmodel

Tags: c#

In my ASP.NET MVC code, I like to use controller service classes for my controllers. These service classes contain methods for retrieving viewmodel objects.

Here is an example controller snippet:

```
public SubscriptionsController(ISubscriptionsControllerService service)
{
    _service = service;
}

public ActionResult Index(Guid id)
{
    return View("Subscriptions", _service.GetSubscriptionsViewModelOnGet(id));
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SubscriptionsViewModel viewModel)
{
    _service.SaveSubscriptions(viewModel);

    return View("Subscriptions", _service.GetSubscriptionsViewModelOnPost(viewModel));
}
```

As you can see, I have a method for retrieving the subscriptions viewmodel on a GET request, as well as the equivalent for a POST request.

The POST method takes in an existing viewmodel object and updates any relevant data e.g. a list of subscription items, that need to be refreshed before passing back to the view.

My question is whether the naming of the methods (`GetSubscriptionsViewModelOnGet()` and `GetSubscriptionsViewModelOnPost()`) makes sense. They seem OK to me, but I'm interested in other people's views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not name them both the same? The difference is the type of parameter you're passing. This leaves you free to do some method overloading:

```
public SubscriptionsViewModel GetSubscriptionsViewModel(Guid id)
{
    //GET Logic here...
}

public SubscriptionsViewModel GetSubscriptionsViewModel(SubscriptionsViewModel viewModel)
{
    //POST Logic here...
}
```

Why call them the same? They both *do* the same: return a `SubscriptionsViewModel`.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same thing this morning, just before I posted this question. I think it does not matter about the context of when the code is getting the viewmodel e.g. GET/POST. I can make the method names easier i.e. the same.